# how can i get value from SUM as column in SQL

Tags: sql, mysql, sum

I have a table like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJDHL.png)

How can i add new column with the value of column is the total value of price column with the same no_btsc like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjFc1.png)

i use SUM but its no use. what SQL script i can use with case like this??

i use sum in nested query like this

```
Select id, name, price, no_btsc, (select SUM(price) from table1 group by no_btsc) 
from table 1
```

Comment: You wrote in your question: _I'm new here_ Then take the [tour] and visit the [help] and don't forget to read [ask] and lastly see: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Then [edit] your question accordingly. You may also want to look at how to use [markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: I would implement it with [trigger](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html)s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try it by doing this:

```
SELECT id, price, name, btus_no, SUM(price) OVER (PARTITION BY btus_no) AS total_price   
FROM table1
```

Comment: add order by as well, this gives you the btsc_no wise cumulated sum:  
SELECT id, price, name, btsc_no, SUM(price) OVER (PARTITION BY btsc_no) AS total_price  from table1 order by id;

Answer (score 0):

you can solve this using windows function but you not need to use partition by because you need sum of all the values present in the column

```
SELECT id, price, name, no_btsc, SUM(price) OVER () AS total_price   
FROM t1;
```

if you are looking sum with respective to some values (kind of groups) then you can use partition by in the query

```
SELECT id, price, name, no_btsc, SUM(price) OVER (partition by columns_name) 
AS total_price FROM t1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it is by using cross join to add a value to each row like this:

`SELECT [id], [price], [Name], [btsc_no], [t2].[sum] FROM t1 CROSS APPLY (SELECT SUM([PRICE]) as sum FROM @Table) AS t2`